# How can I keep track of modified values in a Vaadin table?

Tags: java, vaadin, javabeans, vaadin7

I have an **editable Vaadin Table** and I want desperately to track the modified items in it (either edited or added rows).

My main purpsose afterwards is to **save the modified table** and **update** the database after a button click.

Please can you show me a specific example because I'm newbie and I have found nothing helpful until now. 
Here is the same question but the answer wasn't very helpful for me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848939/how-can-i-receive-the-input-of-the-changed-fields-in-vaadin)

**The BeanItem Container Code:**

```
public BeanItemContainer createContainer() {                
       BeanItemContainer<Sct> beans = new BeanItemContainer<Sct>(Sct.class);

       beans.addNestedContainerProperty("secti.sid");
       beans.addNestedContainerProperty("secti.isa");
       beans.addNestedContainerProperty("secti.order");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        PS_SECTION section = list.get(i);

            Long ps =  section.getPS_SECTION();
            String na = section.getNAME();
            Long is = section.getISACTIVE();
            Long or = section.getVORDER();

         Object itemId = beans.addBean(new Sct(na, new BeanSect(ps, is, or)));
    }

    return beans;
}



    ClickListener saveListener = new ClickListener() {              
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {     

                  //What should I put here?

        }
    };
```

Comment: Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html